# How to dynamically assign method combobox

Tags: c#

I have several methods that I want to execute according to the selected value of a combobox.
I'm currently using the following code:

```
switch (comboBox1.SelectedIndex)
{
    case 1:
        // call method1
        break;
    case 2:
        // call method2
        break;
}
```

Is there a good way to get the same thing like if `combobox.selectedIndex == 1` then auto call to method 1?

Comment: The way you are doing it is the best method.  A switch is better than if statements.

Comment: You have already solved your question???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is through the use of delegates:

```
private readonly Dictionary<int, Action> actions = new Dictionary<int, Action>
  {
    { 1, Method1 },
    { 2, Method2 },
    { 3, Method3 },
  };
```

Which allows you to do something like this:

```
actions[comboBox.SelectedIndex]();
```

You could also use reflection, of course, but keeping things statically linked has plenty of benefits :)

Comment: How i can get value if method have return ?

Comment: @user1965804 Use the correct delegate type - for example, `Func<int>`. But there's really lots of possible answers depending on what exactly you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

use reflexion

```
    public int Method0()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("method0");
        return 0;
    }

    public int Method1()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("method1");
        return 1;
    }

    public int Method2()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("method2");
        return 2;
    }



    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)sender;

        System.Reflection.MethodInfo tmp = this.GetType().GetMethod("Method" + comboBox.SelectedIndex.ToString());

        if (tmp==null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("method named '" + "Method" + comboBox.SelectedIndex.ToString() + "' dont exist");
        }
        else
        {
            int result=(int)tmp.Invoke(this, null);
        }


    }
```

Comment: it will be same thing with event,i need something which match the comboBox.SelectedIndex to method like collecting all method to a list and match comboBox.SelectedIndex ?